# How to convert a FORFILES @fsize output to GB?

Tags: file, batch-file, size

I need to know about the size of specific files remotely,

the idea is to input something like:

```
"ip address" batchfile.cmd
```

Desired output:

```
fileName1.ost size 10GB
fileName2.ost size 20GB
fileName3.ost size 20GB
fileName4.ost size 20GB
```

These code works but the size is showed in just in bytes

```
C:\>forfiles /P %userprofile% /M *.ost /S /C "cmd /c echo @file @fsize"
```

many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a rough solution. Not exact calcs, but for your problem it may be sufficient

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    for /r "%userprofile%" %%a in ("*.ost") do (
        set "size=%%~za" & set "unit=B"
        for %%b in (KB MB GB TB PB EB ZB YB) do if 1024 lss !size! (
            set "size=!size:~0,-3!" & set "unit=%%b"
        )
        echo %%~fa %%~za !size!!unit! 
    )

    endlocal
```

**EDITED** For a little more precise version

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    for /r "%userprofile%" %%a in ("*.ost") do (
        set "size=%%~za" & set "unit=B"
        for %%b in (KB MB GB TB PB EB ZB YB) do if 1024 lss !size! (
            set "unit=%%b" 
            if  !size! lss 2147483647 (set /a "size=size/1024") else (set "size=!size:~0,-3!")
        )
        echo %%~fa %%~za !size!!unit! 
    )

    endlocal
```

Comment: `EB ZB YB`? You are thinking too far into future ;-)

Comment: @Stephan, i've been working on system administration for 20 years, and seeing how the storage needed by mail systems increase. So yes, something that can work at least for a year or two :D